# Interaction of completeness and second incompleteness theorems

Tags: reference-request, logic, incompleteness

So I was reading the Wikipedia article on Godel's completeness theorem, the section on its relation to completeness. It says that completeness gives the existence of a model of arithmetic $\mathcal M \models PA$ where $\mathcal M \vdash \neg \text{Cons}(PA)$, but that the Godel number of the any contradiction is non-standard. Unfortunately, Wikipedia gives no citations for this claim.

Why does completeness imply the existence of this model? How does the Godel number of the contradiction being non-standard avoid actually proving that PA is inconsistent? What does "consistent when viewed from outside" mean? How does that work out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there is a hedge here.  If $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent (meaning in some sufficiently nice meta-theory, or the "real world", one cannot prove contradictory statements), then by Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem $\mathsf{PA} \not\vdash \mathrm{Cons}(\mathsf{PA})$, and so by a standard argument it follows that $\mathsf{PA} + \neg \mathrm{Cons}(\mathsf{PA})$ is also consistent.  By Gödel's Completeness Theorem there is a model $\mathcal{M}$ of this theory.  As $\neg \mathrm{Cons}(\mathsf{PA})$ is an existential statement ($(\exists x) ( \varphi(x) )$), there is some object $x \in \mathcal{M}$ which exhibits (from the point-of-view of $\mathcal{M}$) the inconsistency of $\mathsf{PA}$: it codes a proof of some fixed contradiction, using some fixed Gödel numbering.

Now if $x$ corresponded to some standard number $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then that "real" natural number would code a real proof of a contradiction in $\mathsf{PA}$: the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ "knows" that either $m$ is a code of a proof of a fixed contradiction, or it is not, and in the latter case there is no extension $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ in which $m$ can code a proof of an extension.  But this then contradicts our assumption that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent.

---

### Addendum

*(due to a comment below)*

Let's first sort of get a handle on "nonstandard" numbers (and nonstandard models).  Well, first of all, a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is *nonstandard* if it is not isomorphic to the *standard* model; pretty obvious, I guess.  The thing about models of $\mathsf{PA}$ is that they always start the same: if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\mathsf{PA}$, then the first elements of $\mathcal{M}$ are $$0^{\mathcal{M}},\;
1^{\mathcal{M}}{=}S^{\mathcal{M}} ( 0^{\mathcal{M}} ),\;
2^{\mathcal{M}}{=}S^{\mathcal{M}} ( 1^{\mathcal{M}} ),\;
3^{\mathcal{M}}{=}S^{\mathcal{M}} ( 2^{\mathcal{M}} ),\;\ldots$$
and these object satisfy all the usual arithmetic properties of the "real" natural numbers. In fact, we will usually just say that $\mathbb{N}$ is an initial segment of any model of $\mathsf{PA}$.

But can this be all of them? Unfortunately, no.

> Append to the language of $\mathsf{PA}$ a new constant symbol $c$, and let $T$ be the theory extending $\mathsf{PA}$ obtained by adding $\ulcorner n \urcorner < c$ as a new axiom for each natural number $n$ (where $\ulcorner n \urcorner$ denotes the term $\overbrace{S \cdots S}^{n\text{ times}}0$).  By the Compactness Theorem, if $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, then so is $T$.  If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $T$, then consider $c^\mathcal{M}$.  For each natural number $n$, as $\mathcal{M} \models \ulcorner n \urcorner < c$ it follows that $n <^{\mathcal{M}} c^{\mathcal{M}}$.  That is, $c^{\mathcal{M}}$ does not correspond to any natural number.

An object in a *nonstandard* model of $\mathsf{PA}$ which does not correspond to a natural number is called a *nonstandard* number.  One thing should be clear: any nonstandard number comes after all the standard numbers. Of course, if $x \in \mathcal{M}$ is a nonstandard number, then so is $S^{\mathcal{M}}(c)$ and $S^{\mathcal{M}} ( S^{\mathcal{M}} ( c ) )$.  Also, $c$ will have a immediate *predecessor* which is also nonstandard.  In practice, the collection of nonstandard numbers is fairly messy.

One very useful idea is the following.  If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\mathsf{PA}$, we will call a subset $I \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ a *cut* (in $\mathcal{M}$), if it is a nonempty, initial segment of $\mathcal{M}$ which is closed under the successor operator.  (So $\mathbb{N}$ is a cut in any model of $\mathsf{PA}$.  The following fact is interesting:

> ***Overspill Lemma.*** Suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$, and $I \subsetneq \mathcal{M}$ is a cut.  Suppose that $\varphi ( x , y_1 , \ldots , y_n )$ is a formula and $a_1 , \ldots , a_n \in \mathcal{M}$ are such that for each $z \in I$ there is an $x \in I$ such that $$\mathcal{M} \models x \geq z \wedge \varphi ( x , a_1 , \ldots , a_n ).$$
>   Then there is an $x \in \mathcal{M} \setminus I$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi ( x , a_1 , \ldots , a_n )$.

Let's apply this in two ways:

- First, there is no formula $\sigma (m)$ such that $$\mathcal{M} \models \sigma ( x ) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x\text{ is standard}$$
  for any model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ and any $x \in \mathcal{L}$.  (Simply because $\mathbb{N}$ is a cut in any model, and if $\mathcal{M}$ is a nonstandard model, then $\mathbb{N}$ is a proper cut, and so if $\sigma (x)$ is a formula true about all standard numbers, by the Overspill Lemma it must also be true about a nonstandard number.
- It is not difficult to show that if $\mathrm{Formula}_{\mathsf{PA}} (x)$ denotes the formula distinguishing the natural numbers coding formulas from those that do not, then the set of all natural numbers $n$ such that $\mathbb{N} \models \mathrm{Formula}_{\mathsf{PA}} (n)$ is unbounded, and so if $\mathcal{M}$ is a non-standard model of $\mathsf{PA}$, by the Overspill Lemma there is a nonstandard number $x \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \mathrm{Formula}_{\mathsf{PA}} (x)$. But you could not decode this $x$ into an actual formula of $\mathsf{PA}$: it may be of nonstandard ("infinite") length, or it may employ "variables" with nonstandard indices. But as $\mathcal{M}$ can't tell standard numbers from nonstandard numbers, so $\mathcal{M}$ just "thinks" that $x$ codes a formula.

Now, recall that $\mathrm{Cons}(\mathsf{PA})$ is just a formula (sentence). We built it up to have some significance under a suitable interpretation, but this significance critically used the idea that "real" natural numbers were being used.

So what happens if a nonstandard model $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\neg \mathrm{Cons}(\mathsf{PA})$, even if the standard model does not?  Being a bit more exact than above, $\neg \mathrm{Cons} ( \mathsf{PA} ) \equiv (\exists x ) ( \mathrm{Proof}_{\mathsf{PA}} ( x , \ulcorner \psi \urcorner ) )$, where $\psi$ is some fixed contradictory sentence.  If $\mathcal{M} \models \neg \mathrm{Cons} ( \mathsf{PA} )$, then there must be some $x \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \mathrm{Proof}_{\mathsf{PA}} ( x , \ulcorner \psi \urcorner ) )$.  But if $x$ were a standard number, it would follow that $\mathbb{N} \models \mathrm{Proof}_{\mathsf{PA}} ( x , \ulcorner \psi \urcorner ) )$, which we have assumed  cannot be the case.  So such an $x$ must be nonstandard.

Well, what does this mean? According to the definition of $\mathrm{Proof}_{\mathsf{PA}}$ it means that $\mathcal{M}$ "thinks" that $x$ codes a sequence of numbers, and each number in this sequence codes a formula, and these formulas constitute a proof of $\psi$.  But, like the above, something about this encoded "proof" is going to be nonstandard: it may have nonstandard ("infinite") length, or it may involve nonstandard formulas. This says that $x$ does not *really* encode a proof of a contradiction in $\mathsf{PA}$, but only that $\mathcal{M}$ "thinks" that it does.

Comment: I mostly have it, I still don't get how $\mathcal M$ can prove the inconsistency of PA but not inconsistency of itself. What exactly does this x look like? What happens when you apply $Prv_{PA}(x)$ for non-standard $x$? (It doesn't help that my sources aren't so clear on the definition of the provability predicate).

Comment: @fhyve: I have made a rather substantial addition. I hope it clears up some things (though I expect it will also spawn more questions).

Answer (score 6):

Simplifying a little bit, Gödel's Completeness Theorem for first-order logic (with one of the "usual" *proof systems*, i.e. logical axioms+rules of inferences) says that :

> > $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ iff $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$,

i.e. all the *logical consequences* of a set of *sentences* are provable with the (logical) rules and axioms.

If we apply it to $\mathsf {PA}$, we have that $\Gamma$ is the set of f-o Peano's axioms.

The above theorem says that all f-o formulae of $\mathsf {PA}$ that are provable from Peano's axioms are *logical consequences* of the axioms, i.e. they must be *true* in **all** models of the axioms.

Godel's Incompletenss Theorem says that $\mathsf {PA} \nvdash Cons(\mathsf {PA})$.

But, **if** we assume $\mathsf {PA}$ consistent, and this assumption is necessary for the proof of G's Incompletenss Th, we have that the formula $Cons(\mathsf {PA})$ is *true*.

$Cons(\mathsf {PA})$ being *unprovable* from f-o Peano's axioms, we have that it is **not** a *logical consequence* of the axioms.

And if it is not a logical consequence of the axioms, it is not true in **all** models of the axioms, i.e.it must be false in some of their models.

But we know that it is true in the "standard" model $\mathbb N$; thus, it must be *false* in some "non-standard" model.

Then, Arthur's argument follows.